AWS Kinesis - GetShardIterator on shard XXX in stream XXX under account XXX is invalid because it did not come from this stream
so here is my issue.
Did enable DynamoDB Amazon Kinesis Data Streams for DynamoDB and created the Amazon Kinesis datastream for it.
Created and ETL job with the Kinesis datastream as source and Redshift as destination with some transformations in between.
For some reasons I deleted the Amazon Kinesis datastream where Amazon Kinesis Data Streams for DynamoDB was streaming to, and created a new one with the exact same name.
Now the ETL job returns
GetShardIterator on shard shardId-000000000001 in stream my-stream-name under account XXXXXXXXXXXX is invalid because it did not come from this stream.

How can I fix this without having to drop the main DynamoDB table?

Your consumer is still trying to read from the original stream, which has unique shard-ids. Make sure you reset your consumer to listen to the new stream, which is probably easier done if you change its name rather than using the same name.
